# Is the determinant of a matrix multiplied by its transpose equal to the determinant of the matrix's transpose multiplied by the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Is

$$
      det(AA^T) = det (A^TA)
$$

for any rectangular matrix true?

Comment: The true result "close" to this is that over the reals the two matrices have the same set of non-zero eigenvalues with the same multiplicities..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $A=[1\cdots 1]\in M_{1,n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $n\ge2$.

We have $A^TA=n$ and so $\det(A^TA)=n$

But $AA^T$ has rank $1<n$ hence $\det(AA^T)=0$

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is a square matrix then $det(A^T A) = det(AA^T)$. However if $A$ is not square then the following theorem is helpful:
$A^T A$ is an invertible matrix if and only if the column vectors of $A$ are linearly independent.
This means that if $A$ has more columns than rows then the column vectors can't be L.I and thus $A^T A$ isn't invertible and has $det(A^TA)=0$.  However, $A A^T$ might be invertible and thus have a non-zero determinant because $A^T$ has more rows than columns and so the column vectors of $A^T$ could be L.I. (This last statement uses the same theorem, but considers $A^T$ to be the original matrix, and of course, its transpose is $A$.)

Comment: You can find a tutorial on how to format math here -> https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference